# Show files from terminal command results in Finder

Tags: macos, find, finder

I can find original files in a directory (as opposed to hard links) in Terminal with

```
find ./ -type f -links 1 -name file2find
```

How can I view the results in a single Finder window?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about revealing the file, use `exec` and `open -R`. This will open a Finder window and highlight the file:

```
find . -type f -links 1 -name file2find -exec open -R {} \;
```

Note that this only works for *one* file, since repeated calls to `open -R` will not open a new Finder window, but re-use the existing one(s) to change the highlighted file.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get all the results in a single window.

Comment: So do you expect your `find` command to return multiple files in different folders? And do you expect Finder to show these files all in *one* window?

Comment: Yes.  Like a Finder search normally does, but Finder seems to return some hard links whereas the bash command returns what I want.

Comment: Hm, there's no way other to do this through an actual Finder Spotlight search… so your real search requirement is what, exactly?